# Lisp path from root to given node using MAP functions

Tags: tree, lisp

I have been thinking about this for a while but I can't figure it out myself. Given a n-ary tree and a node, find the path, in lisp (i'm using common lisp but it's ok any version of it), to a given node.A n-ary tree is like this: `(root (subtree1) (subtree2) (subtree3) ...)`, for example `(A (B (C) (D)) (E (F) (G)) (H (I) (J)))` is represented like this:

```
           A
       /   |   \
      B    E    H
     /\    /\   /\
    C D   F G  I  J
```

Given the three `(A (B (C) (D)) (E (F) (G)) (H (I) (J)))` and the node `F`, the result should be: `(A E F)`.

P.S.: I've searched for a solution using `map` functions but I found only recursive solutions without `map` functions.

Comment: why do you want to use `map` for this?

Comment: I was asked to do so, I had to do one implementation using MAP functions and one without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a contrived solution using `mapcan` *together* with recursion:

```
(defun path (tree leaf)
  (cond ((null tree) nil)
        ((eq (car tree) leaf) (list leaf))
        (t (mapcan (lambda (subtree)
                     (let ((p (path subtree leaf))) 
                       (when p (cons (car tree) p))))
                   (cdr tree)))))
```

Comment: @J. Newbie - In general, when you want to map through a list and have some elements (such as the `B` and `H` nodes) produce _nothing_ (because they do not contain `F`), then `mapcan` and `mapcon` are your friends.

Comment: Thank you a lot, now i'm clarified!